# Problem with sluggable cyrillic symbols with iconv()

Tags: php, symfony, utf-8, ascii, iconv

I try to transliterate cyrillic words using iconv php function.

```
$s = 'Електроінструмент';
$s = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $s);
```

But i always get

> Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string

How i cat to solve this problem?

I use php 7.4, symfony 5 and Ubuntu 20 server. This iconv function using in KNP Sluggable bundle for symfony.

Comment: What is the cyrillic input string?

Comment: Електроінструмент

Comment: I think you need `CP1251` for cyrillic characters.

Comment: When i use CP1251 i get empty string

Comment: Well, test without `//TRANSLIT`. If I remember correctly, this is also a reason for a notice.

Comment: without //TRANSLIT the same notice

Comment: It works as expected, when my PHP file is `UTF-8` encoded and with `CP1251` as second parameter for `iconv()`. But when the PHP file is `Windows-1251` encoded, I receive exactly the same error. Check the encoding of your source files and choose the appropritae code page for `iconv()`.

Comment: I checked encoding using "file --mime" command and it is charset=utf-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to symfony 5.0 fixed it.